# Problem setting the width of a column with multirow command

Tags: tables, multirow

I have an issue with the width of a column. I have a long word in a cell which is larger than the column width, I've tried with `\parbox`, changing the width of the box and the column, but I can't fix it. Here's the code, I loaded the needed packages, `multirow` and `array`:

```
  \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{array}
   \usepackage{multirow}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{table}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|>     {\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|>          {\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm}|}
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{text} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{text text text text text text text} & \multirow{2}{*}{thereisalongwordhere}\\
 \cline{2-5}
 & text & text & text & text &\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please always post complete documents it makes modifying the code much easier. It isn't clear what result you want here, for example does the last column have to be m or can it simply be `c` and fill to its natural width the same as the `*` specifier for multirow.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've just uploaded with the problem with a long word.

Comment: You added an image but that's what I saw when I ran it locally, that's why I asked in the comment what you want to do, just simply changing the last column to `c` would make it wider, but perhaps you need it to be an m column for other reasons not shown in this example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I appreciate your answer, but changing for 'c', I can't fix it. On the other hand, only with the code of the heading of my table, exists the issue.

Comment: Can you please post a complete MWE? I have trouble guessing which one of the many tabular extension packages you are using.

Comment: what do you mean by "can't fix it" It would make the last column wide enough to take the long word which is the question. If it causes problems it is in part of the table not shown, which makes it hard to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is that you had more column specifiers than columns so the last column specifier was never used.

[image]

Note this is a *complete* document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{
|c|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{33mm}|
}
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{text} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{text text text text text text text} & \multirow{2}{*}{thereisalongwordhere}\\
 \cline{2-5}
 & text & text & text & text &\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}


\bigskip


 \begin{tabular}{%
|c|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13mm}|
c|}
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{text} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{text text text text text text text} & \multirow{2}{*}{thereisalongwordhere}\\
 \cline{2-5}
 & text & text & text & text &\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```